# Set default value for product attribute in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

When i add **configurable** product with **associated** products, associated products types are changed to **virtual** product.

When i change weight field value is **This item has weight** then the product type was changed to virtual to simple

How to set default value to **product has weight** attribute for associated products.

Or

Change product type virtual to simple while adding associated product in create configurations.

```
<field name="product_has_weight" group="product-details" />
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create a product without weight you create a virtual product. You should convert your product to a simple one and then update its weight.